# Problem on solving gradle dependencies when building to Android

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I'm stuck on solving flutter dependencies to Android since I started upgrading the project to AndroidX. So I just create a new project (0 custom dart files) and started adding the packages of my main project until solving the dependencies. So the problem is only relate to build settings on android and on ios works perfectly.

The project compiles until I add the `firebase_aut` package (any version that supports androidX):

```
ERROR: Could not find com.com.myapp.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/com/myapp/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/com/myapp/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/com/myapp/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/com/myapp/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.jar
Required by:
    project :firebase_auth
```

It's looking on the wrong url. If I take off `com/myapp` from the url it can find the needed files for the projects.

My build files:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha04'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my src structure:

```
android
    >app
        >src
            >debug
                >AndroidManifest.xml
            >main
                >java
                    >com
                        >myapp
                            >app
                                >MainActivity.java
     ...
```

My gladle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

The dependencies from my pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_redux: ^0.5.3
  meta: ^1.1.6
  redux: ^3.0.0
  redux_persist_flutter: ^0.8.1
  flutter_markdown: ^0.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^1.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0+2 
  flutter_range_slider: 1.1.0
  just_debounce_it: ^2.1.0
  camera: ^0.4.0+3
  image_picker: ^0.5.0+3
  exif: ^1.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  image: ^2.0.7
  transparent_image: ^0.1.0
  share_extend: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  flutter_native_image:
    git: https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git
  intl: ^0.15.7
  badges: ^0.0.6
  url_launcher: ^5.0.1
  geolocator: ^3.0.1
  geoflutterfire: #^2.0.0
    git: https://github.com/felipecesar42/GeoFlutterFire.git
```

I already tried many variations of the buildscript repository.

I already tried using Android Studio > Refactor to android X. I have no more old usages to refactor

Comment: Did you add android.enableJetifier=true & android.useAndroidX=true in gradle.properties for androidx migration?

Comment: Good point. Yes. I just updated the question showming my gradle.properties :)

Comment: I tested your code. Everything is working when I changed application id in app/build.gradle. Are you sure you added proper google-services.json? And also check if androidmanifest is also inside main folder.

Comment: Yes. If you put the wrong-services the error is different. It works fine until I add the `firebase_auth` in the pubspec. Have you also tried add it?

Comment: Yes I tested your gradle with my existing firebase project. It is working fine. Can you post your pubspec.yaml file also? While androidx migration, if any one of the packages is also androidx incompatible, it will not build though.

Comment: Hm... strange. Maybe I gonna have to try reset my android studio and flutter installation in the meantime. Anyway... I just edited the question with my pubspec. Thanks again for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the main problem. Sometimes I was trying to clean the cache manually to try to make sure I wouldn't run with some problem with the cache later and I was using `rm -Rf /Users/felipe/flutter/.pub-cache && flutter clean` and then `flutter get packages`. But, when you remove the .pub-cache folder it doesn't repair automatically when downloading packages. So refresh the flutter installation allowed me to debug each package individually.

I started a new project and added each packet manually trying to avoid using `Android Studio > Refactor to Android X` and the automatic gradle update it offers.

Here my currents files:

build.grade

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha04'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gladle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+4
  flutter_redux: ^0.5.3
  meta: ^1.1.6
  redux: ^3.0.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.5+2
  flutter_range_slider: ^1.1.0
  just_debounce_it: ^2.1.0
  camera: ^0.4.2
  image_picker: ^0.5.0+6
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  transparent_image: ^0.1.0
  share_extend: ^1.0.4
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  flutter_native_image:
    git: https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git
  intl: ^0.15.7
  badges: ^0.0.6
  url_launcher: ^5.0.1
  geolocator: ^3.0.1
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+2
  redux_persist_flutter: ^0.8.1
```

Thanks to @Xuzan, as I saw he could compile the project it helped me to troubleshoot  the problem :)